# WSO2 Console: how to keep two consoles up?

Tags: console, wso2, soa, wso2-esb

this is a straightforward question about my work on your SOA architecture.

I noticed that if I login into a console (for example `https://localhost:9443/carbon/`, where is my ESB), and then login into **another** console (for example `https://localhost:9444/carbon/`, where is my BAM), the first crashes (bringing me to the login page), even if the user is different.

Do you know if and how it's possible to keep on two different consoles (belonging to two different architecture components)?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the "remember me" option in both consoles and worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have properly set the port offset value in the `${carbon.home}/repository/conf/carbon.xml` file of the 2nd server. Can you please post here the error log of the failed server?

Comment: Offset has been set (sorry for the wordgame :P)
The server logs only "Axis Engine access denied. Please login first", but not always, only sometimes.
The server stays up, only the login status is nullified.

I've just tried using two different browsers (Chrome and Explorer) and in both cases if I open two consoles in tabs I'm automatically logged out (from both). If, though, I open **one console per browser**, I will be allowed to be logged in.

Thanks for the support, if you find out a better solution, please tell me :-)